# Flex Drawing Library

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Do you know any simple drawing libraries with align support (one component to other, also align to grid)
I would like to implement simple editor of wall configuration in the apartments, by the way.
Or, may be, there is no such component and is better to use Graphics class?

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://www.rogue-development.com/objectHandles.html